# How to delete records of previously used Python interpreters in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda3

I do not know where these records are placed and how to delete them in a normal way.
I am using Win11 and I attempted to delete these folder:

- %APPDATA%\Code
- %USERPROFILE%.vscode

But it is not worked.

Comment: what kind of interpreters are you referring to here?

Comment: python interpreters

Comment: What if you use the refresh button at the top right of the panel for selecting an interpreter? (the panel you get when you click the interpreter indicator at the bottom right of the screen)

Comment: ![flush_interpreters](https://github.com/RockmanJim/git_pic/blob/main/CPU_high/flush_interpreters.png?raw=true "flush_interpreters")

Comment: There has been no change.

I am starting to consider that vscode automatically retrieves data from certain locations, rather than past personal usage records.

I discovered this article, although my English proficiency is limited and I don't understand what code is used or how to implement it, it also gave me some inspiration.

But I still suspect that vscode has some caching mechanism.

Comment: [Interpreter and Environment Discovery](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Interpreter-and-Environment-Discovery)